# Setting to follow Unison's recommended action

Tags: unison

I use unison to sync a couple of directories between my laptop and desktop. Whenever there are new files on one system, I have to confirm each one individually:

```
             <---  new file   c  [f]
```

I've scoured through the [docs](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#prefs), but I can't seem to find a setting that will just auto-accept unison's recommendation. Is there one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, the option `-auto` is what you're looking for. From the documentation:

> **auto** 
>  
>   When set to true, this flag causes the user interface to skip asking for confirmations on non-conflicting changes. (More precisely, when the user interface is done setting the propagation direction for one entry and is about to move to the next, it will skip over all non-conflicting entries and go directly to the next conflict.)

Also of interest:

> **batch** 
>   When this is set to true, the user interface will ask no questions at all. Non-conflicting changes will be propagated; conflicts will be skipped.